# Color to String

Tags: netbeans

Btn1.setBackground(BLUE);

Color holdcolor =  btn1.getBackground

if (holdcolor = "java.awt.Color[r=0,g=0,b=255]"){

```
     Btn1.setBackground(GREEN);
  }
```

"Incompatible types: color canot be converted to string"

I want the color of the button to say Blue untill(another button is pressed) then it returnes to its normal color or in this casr Green. This example  button turnes Blue on first press then Green on second press.

Thanks

Comment: Can you clarify your problem? i.e. what are you expecting and what are you getting instead.

Comment: FIXED IT: stupid me:                                                                     Btn1.setBackground(BLUE);                                                             Color holdcolor = Btn1.getBackground();
                                                                  TextDisplay.setText(""+holdcolor);   forgot the ""+Var  =                                                                                                       **java.awt.Color[r=0,g=0,b=255]